# Angular9: why is the Subject not firing inside the tap operator?

Tags: angular, rxjs, subject

I have a tap operator inside my login function where I trigger a `Subject` and save something in the `localStortage`. The variable is saved in `localStorage` but the `Subject` does not fire.

```
    login({ username, password }: any): Observable<any> {
    return from(
      this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(username, password)
    ).pipe(
      tap((resData) => {
        const uid: string = resData.user.uid;
        this.loggedInUser.next(uid);
        localStorage.setItem('lu', JSON.stringify(uid));
      })
    );
}
```

I am subscribing to it in another component but nothing happens there:

```
this.authenticationService.loggedInUser.
     subscribe(user => console.log(user)) //nothing happens here
```

Where is the problem? am I doing something wrong with the operators?

Comment: Try changing take(2) to be take(1)

Comment: It is not about the take. I deleted the second subscription as you can see above. it is still not firing

Comment: Okk, then try using map instead of tap operator

Comment: It is likely that you subscribe to the subject after it already fired. You might try a behaviourSubject instead..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where and when are you subscribing to the `login` function?

You need to have something like this for your logic to be fired.

```
const userPwd = { username: 'MyName', password: 'MyPwd' };
login(userPwd).subscribe(
  next: resp => {
    // do something with the response
  },
  err => {
    // handle error
  },
  () => {
    // do something when the Observable completes; probably nothing since it looks like an Observable which emits just once
  }
)
```

Plus you may not need to use a `Subject` here. You can have something like this

```
login({ username, password }) {
    return from(
      this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(username, password)
    ).pipe(
      map((resData) => { // instead of firing a Subject within a tap operator you use map and return the uid 
        const uid = resData.user.uid;
        localStorage.setItem('lu', JSON.stringify(uid));
        return uid
      })
    );
}

const userPwd = { username: 'MyName', password: 'MyPwd' };
this.authenticationService.logIn(userPwd).
     subscribe(user => console.log(user)) //something should happen here
```

If `login` is subscribed in two different components, you may need to share the subscription (i.e. just call the remote auth service once) and you may have a problem of timing.

Let's assume `login` is first subscribed by component **C1** and then by component **C2** and that you want to call `this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(username, password)` just one time and share the result between **C1** and **C2**.

In this case you may use the operator `shareReplay` to achieve your goal, like here

```
login({ username, password }) {
    return from(
      this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(username, password)
    ).pipe(
      map((resData) => { // instead of firing a Subject within a tap operator you use map and return the uid 
        const uid = resData.user.uid;
        localStorage.setItem('lu', JSON.stringify(uid));
        return uid
      }),
      shareReplay(1). // 1 means that only the last value is cached and repalyed
    );
}
```

Comment: I am subscribing to the login function in one component and listening to the subject in another component. I will try your suggeston

Comment: In case you share the `login` among more components, you may need to cache the result via `shareReplay`. I have edited my answer considering this case.

Comment: thanks. not exactly the behaviour I was looking for. but for now, I am using it